# React w/ Redux Provider

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add Redux to me existing React project, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you simply forgot to pass the store as a property to the App. Try this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App store={store} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

This assumes you called your store, `store` when you used the `createStore` function.

Comment: You should pass the store in the Provider

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'
​
const store = createStore(rootReducer)
​
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

you need to pass the store can follow this small example from here
https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list